# Unit testing the click event of Highchart directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, highcharts

I am using highchart in my app and everything is working fine. Now I would like to unit test the click event of the data point. This is how the simplified code looks for

**Directive**

```
<highchart config="vm.chartConfig"></highchart>
```

**Controller.js**

```
vm.chartConfig = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (e) {
                            //redraw chart (excluded for simplicity)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: dates
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    series: [{ data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4] }]
};
```

How can i write tests for the click event?

Comment: Hi, did you find some good resource or tutorial? or how did you fulfilled this automation testing? Thanks in advance.